# Implement undoable MongoDB transaction in Meteor/React

Tags: mongodb, reactjs, meteor, rollback, undo

In my [app](https://ideal-engine.herokuapp.com/DisplayTable/c1066219d82d1bd2912a52a7), I have a table that is loaded from MongoDB and which allows the user to do in-line editing.

Currently, I am just subscribing to the database(s) and sending the changes directly there. This precludes any kind of undo operation, but it makes state alterations incredibly easy.

I could store the last 3 operations on a stack and just apply the converse when an undo button is pressed, but I was wondering if there was a proper way to do it in Mongo/Meteor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may find one of these solutions to be helpful:

https://atmospherejs.com/babrahams/transactions

https://atmospherejs.com/adain/meteor-command-pattern

Comment: Thank you, I'll look into those!